# How to prevent body from moving after collision [Box2D] [AndEngine]

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I am making a game using AndEngine and Box2D. I am making a pong style football game and I want keeper to act like a static body when ball collides with it. When they collide keper moves too and it makes my game unplayable. I have tried to do something using contactListener but it doesnt work.

Comment: is the keper body type `Kinematic`?

Comment: Its body type is Dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the body type of the keeper as `Kinematic`.

> A kinematic body is an hybrid body which is not affected by forces and
>   collisions like a static body but can moved with a linear velocity
>   like a dynamic body.

You can move it, but if it gets hit by a ball it wont move.

Comment: I forgot to say that the keeper must stay between two goal posts. So keeper must collide with that posts

Comment: can't you limit that with X/Y position?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt worked. It is so weird :/ I found a solution but it isnt good enought. I set a friction joint with a big friction  value. So it stop moving just after collision but it moves a bit. When I want to move keeper myself I set velocity continuesly while key pressed But as I said it moves a bit after collision so it is not a perfect solution

Comment: I'm assuming the goal post don't change position. Why would it be hard to limit the keeper X/Y position?

Comment: I dont know but I tried that code but if doesnt help:

   if( post[0].getX() < keper.getX() && post[1].getX > keper.getX())
       //move keeper

Comment: I have changed all of my onAreaTouched methods and I applyForceToCenter instead of setting velocity directly and it worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the keper body type static? That way it will have infine mass and not move,
[read more here.](http://www.matim-dev.com/differences-between-body-types.html)

Comment: I want it to move to catch the ball. You cant move static bodies.